# ASP.Net MVC Controller cannot see another namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC Controller that cannot see another namespace in the using statement.

Specifically this line of code:

```
using TRN.Website.Tools;
```

Errors with:

> The type or namespace name 'Tools' does not exist in the namespace
>   'TRN.Website' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Other parts of my project can see the TRN.Website.Tools namespace however.

I tried adding the namespace to web.config but this had no effect.

EDIT: Sorry all I have missed out a vital bit of information. TRN.Website.Tools is just a folder with the namespace TRN.Website.Tools in the same project. It is not a separate project or a dll.

Comment: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Have you import the dll into your project references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ASP.NET MVC project does not contain a reference to the assembly that contains the `TRN.Website.Tools` namespace. You have to reference that from your ASP.NET MVC project in order to use it.

If `TRN.Website.Tools` is a project in your Solution, you can just add a Project reference to it.

If it isn't a project in your Solution, you'll have to add a reference to the compiled DLL to your ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: Accepted as while this did not solve my problem it was a well written answer that will help others.

Answer (score 3):

My guess: You have multiple projects in you solution and you have multiple libraries (dlls) that their names starts with `TRN.Website` and you added reference to one of these dlls in your MVC project. you have to add reference to the other one too.

Answer (score 3):

Solved but in a really strange way.

I added another class in the Tools folder and after that the error disappeared.

Very very odd.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Build Action of your class in properties window. It must be 'Compile'.

Comment: I even added the 'aspnet folder' App_Code and the class default action was set to content.  Amazing that five years later (using MVC5) and stuff like this still trips us up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not checked in the "X.csproj" file to TFS, so the new controller I created was not being found in my testing environments as a valid controller.